# difference between Iterator and Iterable interfaces according to SE8

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

I was going through the documentations of Iterator and Iterable interfaces of Java 8. Please find the links to the documentation below. I could not understand the difference specially because the recently added forEachRemaining method of the Iterator seems very similar to the forEach method of Iterable. I would really appreciate if someone can help me understand the difference between methods above also the difference between Iterator and Iterable in general and their respective uses as per the latest version java 8.

[Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

[Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-)

Comment: Have you checked the default implementations? It should show you the path.../

Comment: An Iterable is a collection which you can create an Iterator from. It isn't much more complicated than that.  There are subtle differences as you mention but that is covered by the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEachRemaining()` will apply an action to all the elements that can be reached with the method `next()` **from the current `Iterator`'s state**.
`forEach()` will apply an action to all the elements of an `Iterable`.

They have the same effect if you use `forEachRemaining()` on a `Iterator` that has not called `next()` yet.
However, you can start iterating with `next()` until you reach a certain condition, then apply an action to the remainder of the `Iterable` with `forEachRemaining()`.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the documentation of an interface, you should mainly focus on methods which are not `default`, because default methods are just methods that are implemented using the other, non-default methods.

If you just take into account the non-default methods, you realize that an Iterable is a class that has an `iterator()` method returning an `Iterator`. For example: Collection is such a class: every collection can be iterated using an Iterator that it provides and is able to traverse the collection.

Default methods are just implemented on top of that capability of getting an Iterator out of the Iterable.

`forEach()` gets the iterator out of the Iterable and does something *for each* element of the iterable.

`forEachRemaining()` does something for all the *remaining* elements of the iterator (because you might have called `next()` several times on the iterator before calling `forEachRemaining()`). But yes, these two are very close to each other. A notable difference is that, for most iterables, you can call forEach() several times, and will make several passes through the elements. On the contrary, `forEachRemaining()` consumes all the elements of the iterator, and calling it a second time won't do anything, since there is no next element anymore.